# What is the nuance of か and ね together, e.g. ありませんかね?

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, particles, sentence-final-particles

A friend approached me asking what some text meant in this game he was playing which said:

> スリーサイズを当てるって課題、ありませんかね☆

I feel like I understand the gist of what this means but I've been unable to render this into English. I am mostly having trouble with the nuance/meaning of the particles か and ね put together.

If I had to give a translation it might be:

> You don't have any questions, like what are my three sizes, don't you?

Which I feel is horribly wrong, but it's all I can muster at the moment.

From what I understand スリーサイズ is Three sizes, i.e. body measurements,　当てる means to guess, so in this case, guess her three sizes, and the って課題 is a contraction of という課題 I think, which would be like a noun modification/qualification in that the 課題 is the スリーサイズを当てる.

Aside from ありませんかね, 課題 also is giving me some trouble because I traditionally understood this to mean topic or subject usually in the context of like schoolwork and textbooks, but looking it up in the dictionary it also lists the meanings "task, challenge, question," and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**~かね**

As another user mentioned, the function of ね in ~かね can be to soften the question, but it is also used for questions where the asker is wondering whether or not others have the same question. I see the latter a lot, and the answer, if there needs to be one, is just そうですね.

**話題**

話題 in this case would probably be translated as challenge, as it seems to be referring to content in the game itself.

**ありませんか**

I would like to point out that one piece that you overlooked is that this question is grammatically confirming the positive by asking the negative (the proper term escapes me right now). This part should look like "Don't you...?" or "Doesn't it...?" if you translate it without context.

Honestly, it seems like you have a good grasp of the individual grammar points and meanings of each vocabulary, but putting it together can definitely be hard when you are learning and there is little context.

I would probably translate this sentence as:

> I wonder if there is going to be a "Guess My Measurements" challenge?

Comment: Can I ask why I am being downvoted? More than willing to fix my answer if I somehow missed something.

Answer (score 1):

The 課題 puzzles me too. But the かね is just a question, with ね added to reach out to the listener, seeking their confirmation, which is a typical Japanese way of softening a question.